# How to compute this numerical integral in Python?

Tags: python, sympy, numeric, numerical-integration

I have a list of vectors:

```
x = [x1, x2, x3, x4]
```

where `x1,..` are some variables.
I have another matrix

```
b = array([[0, 2],
       [0, 3],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 3],
       [2, 3]])
```

At the end I would like to calculate the following:

```
Integral[ np.exp(-np.dot(np.ones(len(b)),np.cos(x[b[:,0]]-x[b[:,1]]))), {x1, 0, Pi}, {x2,0,Pi}...]
```

So it seems like when the size of `x` is large, it is better to define `x` symbolically

```
from sympy import *
x = symarray('x', 4)
```

and since `x` contains variables that will be integrated out, is there any good way to set up the integral through symbolic variables and do the evaluation at the end?

Update:

Here is one code snippet which does what I want, but the code is really really slow.

```
x =symarray('x', M0)
ij_args = x[b[:,0]]-x[b[:,1]]
ij_cosargs = [cos(ij_args[i]) for i in range(len(ij_args))]
integrand = exp(np.sum(ij_cosargs))
integrate(integrand, (x[0], 0, np.pi), (x[1], 0, np.pi), (x[2], 0, np.pi), (x[3], 0, np.pi))
```

One more problem with the above code is that I have to enter bounds for each symbol separately, like `(x[0], 0, np.pi)`

Comment: Your function inside the integral outputs vectors. It's unclear to me what you want the output to be.

Comment: Probably you should compute the integral for one element of the output in terms of symbols and then substitute values from the array afterwards. The question isn't clear enough for me to give a code example for how to do this.

Comment: @orlp Sorry, I have edited the question to make it more clear. The argument to exponent was vector, but it should actually have been a scalar. I fixed it now.

Comment: @matttree Eh, isn't `np.dot` with `np.ones` just a convoluted way of writing the sum?

Comment: @orlp It is, but in general this matrix which I dotted with is not a matrix will all entries of 1s, so I just kept it as it is so that generalisations are possible.